# Accessibility - how do I find contrast problems?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find good tools for checking accessibility. One of the tools I tested said I should put set CSS `background-color` whenever I set CSS `color`.

Unfortunately that is not really an option for me, but I can see why the say so: `color` is explicitly inherited, but `background-color` is not. However `background-color` is kind of implicitly inherited because child HTML elements are (normally) contained within the parent element on the screen.

Now, with the last assumption (implicit inheritance), is there any way to find HTML elements where a contrast problem actually occur? Javascript? Chrome Workspace? FF dito?

Comment: Do you want to write this custom or just check your stuff ?

Comment: I just want to check my own stuff at the moment, @user2515563.

Comment: then any of the utilities i mentioned in my answer should help you... i tried a few

Comment: Yes, I am looking at them to find out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of utilities to check your content for accessibility problems.

[10 colour contrast checking tools to improve the accessibility of your design](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/10_colour_contrast_checking_tools_to_improve_the_accessibility_of_your_design/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out WAVE at http://wave.webaim.org

They have a FireFox plugin, but be warned it's not as up to date as the website, so you might deploy a page and find it fails the online checking even after passing the plugin tests.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome DevTools has a new feature called CSS Overview. Go into your DevTools settings, got to Experiments, and activate CSS Overview. You can then take an overview clip of your site on this, which tells you any contrast issues you may have. For instance, on this site on dark mode, it shows me this:

[image: CSS Color contrast issues from Chrome DevTools]

The AA and AAA refer to the standards of compliance reached.